# Accessing windows folder or file in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

Lets say I want to access a windows file **C:\Users\Documents\Myfolder\whatever.txt** on Ubuntu. Is there any command existing that I can open **whatever.txt** on Ubuntu ? Also What will be the format of path ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132168/access-windows-7-files-from-ubuntu-12-04 explains how to access Windows files from Ubuntu.

Comment: this question belongs on askubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C partition should be mounted somewhere in `/media`. The rest of the path is pretty straightforward.